# Powershell 5 BeginInvoke Parameters

Tags: powershell, input, output, begininvoke

I'm trying to understand parallel processing in PS5.  Everything was straightforward until I came up on the overload of BeginInvoke with two parameters: BeginInvoke<TInput,TOutput>.
Found something on a blog that works well for the TOutput parameter.

```
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 5)
$RunspacePool.Open()

$Inputs  = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]'
$Outputs = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]'

$ScriptBlock = { Get-Random -Maximum 100 }

$Instances = (1..5) | ForEach-Object {
    $Instance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    $Instance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Instance = $Instance
        State = $Instance.BeginInvoke($Inputs,$Outputs)
    }
}

while ( $Instances.State.IsCompleted -contains $False) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
```

Running this and looking at $Output yields the expected result:

PS C:\Users\xyz> $Outputs
10
74
41
56
59

Now when I tried to pass something to the Script Block via $Inputs I never succeeded.  I know that you can do it with AddParameters but I don't like to leave a stone unturned and would like to understand how you can do it with this overload.  Spent a week now looking at resources on the net but could not find a way to do it correctly.  From what I know this will be passed via the pipeline like the $Outputs is at the end. Here is one way ( from the thousand that I tried...) that doesn't work:

```
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 5)
$RunspacePool.Open()

$Inputs  = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]'
$Outputs = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]'

#Let's say I want to add a bias to the random value
$Inputs.Add( [PSCustomObject]@{
        Bias = 100 }
        )

$ScriptBlock = { 
    Param    
    (
    #Hoping to get value from pipeline
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
    [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection]$Bias
    )
    $BiasValue = [PSCustomObject]$Bias[0]
    (Get-Random -Maximum 100) + $BiasValue[0].'Bias' }

#Create the threads
$Instances = (1..10) | ForEach-Object {
    $Instance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    $Instance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Instance = $Instance
        State = $Instance.BeginInvoke($Inputs,$Outputs)
    }
}

#Wait for all threads to finish
while ( $Instances.State.IsCompleted -contains $False) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
```

Of course this code doesn't do anything useful, it's just a test to find out how to get the $Inputs value in the ScriptBlock.  Now $Outputs is completely empty pointing at an error in the ScriptBlock.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are performing a query of a database.  When your query doesn't find any data of course you will get an empty response.

Comment: Ignore the comment above, they just post comment without having a clue about what they're talking about.

Comment: You are doing a query and the query is not returning any data.  You are not getting any errors.  System.Management.Automation is a database query tool.  The first sample you do not have parameters and just getting the results of the script "Get-Random -Maximum 100".  To have inputs, the script needs to have inputs.  Right now the script has not inputs so adding inputs to $Instance will not change the results.

Comment: @jdweng you seem to be confused. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0

Comment: @DougMaurer : I'm not confused.  Windows has a build in database and System.Management.Automation performs queries of the database.

Comment: @jdweng: You _are_ confused, as implied by the feedback from multiple users here. Given that this is no isolated incident, let me offer you the following advice (again): Please only post comments if you (a) fully understand the question and (b) have sufficient subject-matter expertise to provide helpful information. More often than not, your comments aren't just _unhelpful_, but _confusing distractions_, especially if accompanied by irrelevant links (not the case here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this example helps you get a better understanding. The key issue with your code is that your scriptblock is missing its `process` block and the parameter of the scriptblock should be `psobject` or just `object` since what the threads will receive from pipeline (`TInput`) is just a `pscustomobject`, they **do not receive the entire `PSDataCollection<TInput>`**. It's also hard to give an example from PowerShell because it is single threaded.

```bash
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 5)
$RunspacePool.Open()

$Inputs = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]'
$Outputs = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]'

$ScriptBlock = {
    Param(
        # all threads will receive this and process it in parallel
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [psobject] $Bias
    )

    process {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            ThreadId      = [runspace]::DefaultRunspace.Id
            PipelineInput = $Bias
            Result        = (Get-Random -Maximum 100) + $Bias.Value
        }
        Start-Sleep 1
    }
}

$jobs = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
#Create the threads
1..10 | ForEach-Object {
    # simulate input from pipeline
    $Inputs.Add([pscustomobject]@{ Value = $_ })

    # now start processing
    $Instance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    $Instance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    $jobs.Add([PSCustomObject]@{
        Instance = $Instance
        State    = $Instance.BeginInvoke($Inputs, $Outputs)
    })

    # simulate output, ReadAll() will copy the output into a new
    # collection that we can safely read and clear itself
    if ($Outputs.Count) {
        $Outputs.ReadAll()
    }
}

$Inputs.Complete()

# now block until processing is done
do {
    $id = [System.Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitAny($jobs.State.AsyncWaitHandle, 200)
    # if there is any output from threads, consume it
    if ($Outputs.Count) {
        $Outputs.ReadAll()
    }

    if ($id -eq [System.Threading.WaitHandle]::WaitTimeout) {
        continue
    }

    $job = $jobs[$id]
    $job.Instance.EndInvoke($job.State)
    $job.Instance.Dispose()
    $jobs.RemoveAt($id)
}
while ($jobs.Count)

$RunspacePool.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following two changes are required to make your code work:

- Define `$ScriptBlock` with a pipeline-binding parameter that receives a parameter of type `[pscustomobject]` parameter, *not* of type `[System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[pscustomobject]]`, and process that parameter in a `process { ... }` block.

  - Pipeline-binding parameters do not receive *collections*, they receive the *elements* of collections provided as pipeline input, because collections (enumerables) are *enumerated* in the pipeline, i.e. their *elements* are sent to the pipeline *one by one*.
  - To ensure processing of each pipeline input object, a `process { ... }` block is required - see [Piping Objects to Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#piping-objects-to-functions)
- Call `.Complete()` on the [`` [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1] ``](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection-1) collection that serves as the pipeline input, which is required for processing to complete (end).

Here's the modified version of your code (with as few modifications as necessary; additional improvements are possible) - look for `# !!` comment lines to indicate the changes:

```
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, 5)
$RunspacePool.Open()

$Inputs  = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]'
$Outputs = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection[PSObject]'

#Let's say I want to add a bias to the random value
$Inputs.Add( [PSCustomObject]@{
        Bias = 100 }
        )

# !! Call .Complete() on the input collection to ensure that pipeline 
# !! processing ends.
$Inputs.Complete()

$ScriptBlock = { 
    Param    
    (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
      [pscustomobject]$Bias # !! Define the parameter as [pscustomobject]
    )
    process { # !! Use a `process` block to process each input object.
      (Get-Random -Maximum 100) + $Bias.Bias }
    }

#Create the threads
$Instances = (1..10) | ForEach-Object {
    $Instance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock)
    $Instance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Instance = $Instance
        State = $Instance.BeginInvoke($Inputs, $Outputs)
    }
}

#Wait for all threads to finish
while ( $Instances.State.IsCompleted -contains $False) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }

# !! Print the output objects
$Outputs

# !! Clean up.
$Instances.Instance.Dispose()
$RunspacePool.Dispose()
```

Note that `` [System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1] `` is *thread-safe*, so it shouldn't be a problem that multiple runspaces share the *same* output collection instance, `$Outputs`.

Comment: Thank you for this version.  One thing I did not notice at first is that in both answers each thread will process ALL the inputs on their own.  The way that I found to make it work is to add a note property to inputs named assigned and check if it is false, I change it to true when a thread grabs it. If true then return immediately and grab next one.